# PowerPoint VBA change font for a multi selected text

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Changing font in PowerPoint seems easy, this code is working well

```
Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Name = "Courier New"
```

However, when you select multiple text elements inside a textframe, only the last selected element is defined

[image: sample picture]

If I select the "Paragraph" word on first line, then the third paragraph, only the third line is changed.

If I select the third paragraph first, then the "Paragraph" word on first line, only the paragraph word is changed.

How can I changed all elements ? Since I wish to remove the bullet if whole line is selected, how can I identify this within the selection ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no ready-made object to get the content of the discontinuously selected area, MS Word is the same, as I can think of, but I'm afraid to have to work with the WindowSelectionChange event handler to implement it.

[Application.WindowSelectionChange event (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/PowerPoint.Application.WindowSelectionChange)

[Application.WindowSelectionChange event (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.windowselectionchange)

If you think it works, and no one else offers a better way, I'm willing to set aside time to try to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Oscar, It could be the way indeed, unfortunaly in my case, this is not possible, as I launch my code from PowerShell on the fly and not from a presentation with macro enabled

Comment: @CFou If you're launching your code from PowerShell, how could you use Selection and get a multi-selected range?

Comment: From PowerPoint, I have my own external PowerShell toolbar. My goal is to avoid VBA

Comment: @CFou Then why do your title and tag both include VBA? Do you want to use VBA to solve the problem, or do you want to use a solution other than VBA to implement it? If it is other than VBA, I'm afraid you should modify them so that someone with the corresponding ability can have the opportunity to see your question.

Comment: because the way you do it with PowerShell is the same, you use the same methods and properties once you have instanciated the PowerPoint application. So, I was expecting to have more experts and answers with VBA tag rather than PowerShell, since the goal is to modify an office document.